# UITableView not refreshing unless closed then reopened

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView in an app I am working on and I have a button to add to an array that populates the tableview. When I add then open the tableview, the newest item is missing. I have to open the tableview, close it, then reopen it to view the newest entry.

I have tried:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

in the tableviewcontroller and then calling it after I press add with no luck

I have the datasource and delegate set as self, which has been recommended to me with still no luck

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.cartTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.08, blue:0.08, alpha:1.0)
    tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.70, green:0.70, blue:0.70, alpha:1.0)


    items = defaults.array(forKey: "ItemNameArray") as! [String]
    categories = defaults.array(forKey: "ItemCatArray") as! [String]
    sizes = defaults.array(forKey: "ItemSizeArray") as! [String]
    colors = defaults.array(forKey: "ItemColorArray") as! [String]

    if items.isEmpty == true{
        items = [""]
        categories = [""]
        sizes = [""]
        colors = [""]
    }
    cartTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CartCell_Identifier")

    cartTableView.delegate = self;
    cartTableView.dataSource = self;


}

@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    //load data here
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(items.count)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell_Identifier") as! CartCell
    cell.lblItemName.text = items[indexPath.row]
    if colors[indexPath.row] != ""{
        cell.lblItemInfo.text = ("Color - " + colors[indexPath.row] + " | " + "Size - " + sizes[indexPath.row] + " | "  + "Category - " + categories[indexPath.row])
    }else{
        cell.lblItemInfo.text = ("")

    }

    return(cell)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete{
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        sizes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        categories.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        colors.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        defaults.set(items, forKey: "ItemNameArray")
        defaults.set(categories, forKey: "ItemCatArray")
        defaults.set(sizes, forKey: "ItemSizeArray")
        defaults.set(colors, forKey: "ItemColorArray")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.cartTableView.reloadData();
        }
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 65
}
```

Above is my CartViewController

Id like to be able to have the data reload when I add a new item to the array

Comment: Is `loadList` being called (i.e. put a `print("loadList")` in there and see if it prints)? If so, have you tried putting that `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`?

Comment: How are you adding the item to dataSource? can you show dataSource declaration itself too

Comment: Unrelated but multiple arrays as data source is horrible. This is Swift, an **object** oriented programming language. And `return` is **not** a function. Remove the parentheses.

Comment: "Id like to be able to have the data reload when I add a new item to the array" I do not see any code where you add a new item to the array. Please point out that line to me. Thanks.

Comment: 1. You haven't added any item to items array in 'loadList' method before reloading. 2. Until unless your table View Controller isn't in stack i.e. observer isn't added, your 'loadList' method will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the code witch reloads the TableView into the ViewDidAppear class

Answer (score -1):

I ended up solving my own problem. I was assigning the array like this:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    defaults.set(arrayName, forKey: "ItemNameArray")
}
```

so it would not assign when I loaded the cartTableView. Moving this to the button click function solved my problem

Edit: Thank you to everyone that replied. Sorry my question ended up being a stupid mistake